# OpenVPN server running on openvz. How to write iptables rule without masquerade?

Tags: iptables, openvpn, openvz

I am configuring a VPS which is running on openvz as an OpenVPN server using a tun interface.

I am having some trouble with the iptables rule as MASQUERADE is not available.

If MASQUERADE were available, I would write the iptables rules as follows:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

However, given that I am not able to use MASQUERADE, how can I rewrite these rules using SNAT or DNAT instead?

thanks in advance

-------------- EDIT ---------------

Thanks to Olipro for the solution. Here are the rules that worked for me:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

*Where 1.2.3.4 is the public ip address of the openvpn server.*

Comment: Are you configuring iptables inside the container or on the hardware node? By "using a tun interface" do you mean venet (instead of veth)?

Comment: It's a container sold as a VPS so I don't have access to the hardware node. By tun interface I mean tun0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only actually need MASQUERADE if your global IPv4 address changes frequently (such as on ADSL) otherwise, SNAT is generally preferable.

Instead of the MASQUERADE rule, use SNAT like so:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

replace 1.2.3.4 with the actual public IP of the VM... also, I would expect eth0 to be veth0 or venet0 since it's an OpenVZ box.

Comment: Thanks for responding.I have tried this rule instead of the MASQUERADE one, but it doesn't seem to work for me. From the openvpn client I can ping 10.8.0.1 (the openvpn server) but nothing else.

Comment: Having SNAT alone is not enough; you still need filter rules that will permit the SNATted packets to be forwarded.

consider flushing the FORWARD chain in the filter table and setting a default policy of ACCEPT on it if you are unsure whether the cause of failing connections is actually from your filter table rules.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will update the question to show the actual solution.

Comment: BTW: What I was doing wrong the first time is natting to etho, not venet0... doww!